# gstreamer encoding audio and video to avi file

Tags: audio, video, gstreamer, h.264, avi

I am trying to use the gstreamer to encode h264 video and audio in to a single .avi file.
I'm able to encode audio **or** video using this for video:

```
gst-launch-1.0 appsrc name=appsrc ! deinterlace name=deinterlace ! mfxh264enc name=mfxh264enc ! avimux name=mux ! filesink name=filesink  location=test.avi
```

and this for audio:

```
gst-launch-1.0 alsasrc ! queue ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! oggmux ! filesink location=audioTestQueue.mp3
```

I'm trying to combine them according to [this](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-avimux.html) example with this pipe:

```
gst-launch-1.0 appsrc name=appsrc ! deinterlace name=deinterlace ! mfxh264enc name=mfxh264enc ! queue name=queue1 ! mux. alsasrc name=alsasrc ! audioconvert name=audioconvert ! vorbisenc name=vorbisenc ! queue name=queue2 ! mux. avimux name=mux ! filesink name=filesink  location=test.avi
```

this returns an error saying: "could not link queue2 to mux".

I know that the example is using the lame to encode but I rather not using it as it is in the Ugly Plug-ins source when the gstremer [documentation](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-ugly-plugins/html/gst-plugins-ugly-plugins-lamemp3enc.html) 
say: "Note that MP3 is not a free format, there are licensing and patent issues to take into consideration. See Ogg/Vorbis for a royalty free (and often higher quality) alternative."

what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
it seems that when setting the sound to the audiotestsrc and disabling the audio encodeing gstreamer creates the .avi file and I'm able to play it in VLC:

```
gst-launch-1.0 appsrc name=appsrc1 ! deinterlace name=deinterlace1 ! mfxh264enc name=mfxh264enc1 ! queue name=queue11 ! mux. audiotestsrc name=alsasrc1 ! audioconvert name=audioconvert1 ! queue name=queue31 ! mux. avimux name=mux ! filesink name=filesink1 location=test.avi
```

but trying to do the same with alsasrc makes the avi file to save only the audio data without the video:

```
gst-launch-1.0 appsrc name=appsrc1 ! deinterlace name=deinterlace1 ! mfxh264enc name=mfxh264enc1 ! queue name=queue11 ! mux. alsasrc name=alsasrc1 ! audioconvert name=audioconvert1 ! queue name=queue31 ! mux. avimux name=mux ! filesink name=filesink1 location=/home/user/Downloads/HDTest1.avi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging more into the Gstreamer documentation I discovered this:http://trac.gateworks.com/wiki/Yocto/gstreamer/audio#Encoding
where it list all the encoders avilable.

Checking the [avimux](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-avimux.html) again I saw it can receive data in the audio/x-alaw format.
with that fact I can use the [alawenc](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-alawenc.html) that belongs to the gst-plugins-good instead of the [lamemp3enc](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-ugly-plugins/html/gst-plugins-ugly-plugins-lamemp3enc.html).

so my final pipe is as so:

```
gst-launch-1.0 alsasrc name=pulsesrc1 ! audioconvert name=audioconvert1 ! alawenc name=alawenc1 ! queue name=aud1 ! mux. appsrc name=appsrc1 ! deinterlace name=deinterlace1 ! mfxh264enc name=mfxh264enc1 ! mux. avimux name=mux ! filesink name=filesink1 location=HDTest1.avi
```